# set title to JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, super

I am new to Java. My problem is that I have a class names MyClassExp. I have extended it from JFrame. Inside the class, I initiate an object of another class named TabbedFrame. TabbedFrame also extends a class DemoFrame . In DemoFrame, I have the title of the page set using keyword 'super' like:

```
super("Some Title");
```

Now when I run my MyClassExp, even after creating a JFrame as:

```
new JFrame("New Title");
```

I'm still getting the same title i.e Some Title. Is there any way to solve this problem? I've tried a lot to solve it but failed :'(

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense, you say you have a `DemoFrame` that uses `super("Some Title")`, but your create a new `JFrame`??  It's no wonder the title doesn't change...try creating a `new DemoFrame` instead and using `JFrame#setTitle` to change the `DemoFrame`'s title

Comment: 1) Don't extend `JFrame` just use a reference to one.  2) Your current approach creates **2** frames, the 2nd of which is probably never displayed.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Use the API method    `public void setTitle(String title)`.

Answer (score 1):

**-** Inside the **MyClassExp** class's `constructor` use `this.setTitle(String title)` method.

Comment: It doesn't change the title @Kumar Vivek Mitra :((

Answer (score -1):

Just use setTitle("yourTitleName");

for example:

```
setTitle("Currency Converter");
textField.addKeyListener(this);
combo.addItemListener(this);
label.addMouseListener(this);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```