# Jframe's Title not getting changed

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So I have a class called MyFrame that extends JFrame. I have added an object of another class named TabbedFrame as a component to MyFrame Class in MyFrame's constructor like

```
add(new TabbedFrame());
setTitle("Some Title");
setVisible(true);
```

Now the class TabbedFrame extends another class called FrameDemo in which the frame title is defined as :

```
super ("Title One");
```

When I run it, I get Title One as my JFrame's title. But I think it should be Some Title since I've changed it in MyClass's constructor. Here's what the code is so far. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
public MyFrame(){

add(new TabbedFrame());

setTitle("Some Title");


setVisible(true);

}


public static void main(String[] args){

MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();

}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `TabbedFrame` class?

Comment: And FrameDemo class extends...?

Comment: FrameDemo simple extends JFrame branno88

Comment: This question strangely appears similar to this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13322306/1057230), asked a few hours before this one. Your question is hiding the actual information and revealing nothing much. Better would be to take a second look at your question and add the necessary information, so that it can be answered to it's right potential.

Comment: @ShashankKadne the TabbedFrame class extends FrameDemo. In FrameDemo, I see frame's title set by using 'super' keyword.

Comment: @IngilaEjaz Wait a second...Your TabbedFrame extends FrameDemo, and your FrameDemo extends JFrame, and than you are adding TabbedFrame on MyFrame which extends JFrame, right? How can you do that without of having a IllegalArgumentException? I'm totally confused.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: I have figured it out :)

Comment: The first thing I did wrong was that I extended it from JFrame. It should be TabbedFrame. Secondly, addTabbedFrame() would create the TabbedFrame's object in that case the frame's title would be Title One. So add.TabbedFrame must not be there. I shared the answer in case if anyone else goes as stupid as I went. lol

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I did wrong was that I extended it from JFrame. It should be TabbedFrame. Secondly,

```
addTabbedFrame()
```

would create the TabbedFrame's object in that case the frame's title would be Title One. So add.TabbedFrame must not be there. I shared the answer in case if anyone else goes as stupid as I went. lol – Ingila Ejaz 19 hours ago