# Display UserID on every JFrames : Java

Tags: java, swing

I tried to make a functions as, If any user logged into the system, the UserID should be displayed in `jLabel` on all `JFrames` which are available in application. Something display as `Your are logged as +UserID`

Finally I wrote a code for this function and it's compiled without errors. **But,** the system take some time to loading because of *this functioned code* and other `jFrameForms` are not displaying UserID as well. UserID is displayed on Admin Home `JFrame` only. I think my coded way is wrong.

So how can solve this problem? Hope I can get help from here. Thanks in advance!

> **Login JFrame Code :**

```
package view;

import Conn.DBConnection;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Login() {

    initComponents();

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void initComponents() {

    jFramePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jMainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel_SignIn = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLbl_SchoolName1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLbl_SchoolAddress1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLbl_UserID1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txt_UserID = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLbl_Password1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txt_Password = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    jBtn_Login = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jBtn_Recover = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLbl_SchoolLogo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLbl_Credit3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLbl_Credit1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLbl_Border1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jFrameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1670, 926));
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jFramePanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1670, 926));
    jFramePanel.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jMainPanel.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    jMainPanel.setOpaque(false);
    jMainPanel.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jPanel_SignIn.setOpaque(false);
    jPanel_SignIn.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jLbl_SchoolName1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Stencil", 0, 54)); // NOI18N
    jLbl_SchoolName1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
    jLbl_SchoolName1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLbl_SchoolName1.setText("NG/AL - FALAH M.V.");
    jLbl_SchoolName1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jPanel_SignIn.add(jLbl_SchoolName1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(220, 30, 500, 70));

    jLbl_SchoolAddress1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Agency FB", 1, 33)); // NOI18N
    jLbl_SchoolAddress1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
    jLbl_SchoolAddress1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLbl_SchoolAddress1.setText("Poruthota, Kochchikade.");
    jLbl_SchoolAddress1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jPanel_SignIn.add(jLbl_SchoolAddress1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(110, 90, 500, 40));

    jLbl_UserID1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 22)); // NOI18N
    jLbl_UserID1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
    jLbl_UserID1.setText("User ID");
    jPanel_SignIn.add(jLbl_UserID1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(160, 280, 140, 50));

    txt_UserID.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 22)); // NOI18N
    txt_UserID.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
    txt_UserID.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            txt_UserIDMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel_SignIn.add(txt_UserID, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 280, 330, 50));

    jLbl_Password1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 22)); // NOI18N
    jLbl_Password1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
    jLbl_Password1.setText("Password");
    jPanel_SignIn.add(jLbl_Password1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(160, 350, 140, 50));

    txt_Password.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 22)); // NOI18N
    txt_Password.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
    txt_Password.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            txt_PasswordMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel_SignIn.add(txt_Password, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 350, 330, 50));

    jBtn_Login.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 180, 80));
    jBtn_Login.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Eras Bold ITC", 1, 21)); // NOI18N
    jBtn_Login.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jBtn_Login.setText("LOGIN");
    jBtn_Login.setBorderPainted(false);
    jBtn_Login.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    jBtn_Login.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jBtn_LoginActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel_SignIn.add(jBtn_Login, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 420, 330, 50));

    jBtn_Recover.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
    jBtn_Recover.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
    jBtn_Recover.setText("Forgot User ID or Password?");
    jBtn_Recover.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    jBtn_Recover.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    jPanel_SignIn.add(jBtn_Recover, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(300, 470, 330, 50));

    jLbl_SchoolLogo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/SchoolLogo.png"))); // NOI18N
    jPanel_SignIn.add(jLbl_SchoolLogo, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(70, 10, 140, 130));

    jLbl_Credit3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Consolas", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
    jLbl_Credit3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLbl_Credit3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLbl_Credit3.setText("Version 1.0 - Copyright © 2017 Abdul Solutions.");
    jLbl_Credit3.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jPanel_SignIn.add(jLbl_Credit3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 650, 600, 50));

    jLbl_Credit1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Consolas", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLbl_Credit1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLbl_Credit1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLbl_Credit1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/ProLogo.png"))); // NOI18N
    jLbl_Credit1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jPanel_SignIn.add(jLbl_Credit1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 580, 580, 70));

    jLbl_Border1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255), 2, true), " LOGIN ", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Eras Bold ITC", 1, 24), new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255))); // NOI18N
    jPanel_SignIn.add(jLbl_Border1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 200, 600, 370));

    jMainPanel.add(jPanel_SignIn, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 760, 850));

    jFramePanel.add(jMainPanel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(860, 50, 760, 850));

    jFrameLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/SignPageBg.jpg"))); // NOI18N
    jFramePanel.add(jFrameLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 1670, 926));

    getContentPane().add(jFramePanel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 1670, 926));

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}                    

private void jBtn_LoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        if (txt_UserID.getText().equals("admin")&&txt_Password.getText().equals("123250")){       
                new AdminHome().setVisible(true);
                AdminHome.jLbl_UserID.setText(Login.txt_UserID.getText());    //coded for display user id
                this.dispose();

        }else{

        String uid = txt_UserID.getText();
        String pass = txt_Password.getText();
        String user_role = "";
        String sql = "SELECT user_role FROM tch_data WHERE user_id='"+uid+"' and password='"+pass+"' UNION SELECT user_role FROM stu_data WHERE user_id='"+uid+"' and password='"+pass+"'";

        try {
        java.sql.Connection c = DBConnection.dbconmethod();
        Statement s=c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= s.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()){  
                user_role = rs.getString(1);

                }if(user_role.equalsIgnoreCase("ADMIN")){
                        new AdminHome().setVisible(true);
                        AdminHome.jLbl_UserID.setText(Login.txt_UserID.getText());    //coded for display user id
                        this.dispose();

                }else {
                        UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 22));
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "User not Found, Try again!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        txt_UserID.setText(null);
                        txt_Password.setText(null);
                }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }    

}                                          

private void txt_UserIDMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
        txt_UserID.setText(null);
    }
}                                       

private void txt_PasswordMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
        txt_Password.setText(null);
    }
}                                         

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Login().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration                
private javax.swing.JButton jBtn_Login;
private javax.swing.JButton jBtn_Recover;
private javax.swing.JLabel jFrameLabel;
private javax.swing.JPanel jFramePanel;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLbl_Border1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLbl_Credit1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLbl_Credit3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLbl_Password1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLbl_SchoolAddress1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLbl_SchoolLogo;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLbl_SchoolName1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLbl_UserID1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jMainPanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel_SignIn;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField txt_Password;
public static javax.swing.JTextField txt_UserID;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

> **Admin Home JFrame Code:** http://pastebin.com/LcTdAqLf

Comment: You have to update your labels after the user logged in.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [set title to JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322306/set-title-to-jframe)

Comment: *"But, the system take some time to loading because of this functioned code"* - Take a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution

Comment: I think you need to change the way you're thinking about the problem, may be have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-and-gui-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274) example. Basically, you need get the user credentials, validate them and then have some other controller take over the logic for what should be done about it. Separating the logic into small units of work. You can also either pass the reference of the user information to those parties that need it or fall back onto a singleton pattern to provide a single access poin